# What is the origin of the word פְּלַסְתֵּר?

Tags: hebrew, translation, tractate-brachot

The Gemara Berachos (31b) [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.31b.10?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en&p3=Jastrow%2C_%D7%A4%D6%B0%D6%BC%D7%9C%D6%B7%D7%A1%D6%B0%D7%98%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%A8&lang3=bi)

> אֵלֵךְ וְאֶסְתַּתֵּר בִּפְנֵי אֶלְקָנָה בַּעֲלִי, וְכֵיוָן דְּמִסְתַּתַּרְנָא מַשְׁקוּ לִי מֵי סוֹטָה, וְאִי אַתָּה עוֹשֶׂה תּוֹרָתְךָ **פְּלַסְתֵּר**, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר ״וְנִקְּתָה וְנִזְרְעָה זָרַע״.‏

What was Hannah threatening? She said:

> I will go and seclude myself with another man before Elkana, my husband. Since I secluded myself, they will force me to drink the sota water to determine whether or not I have committed adultery. I will be found innocent, and since You will not make Your Torah **false [pelaster],** I will bear children. With regards to a woman who is falsely suspected of adultery and drank the sota water, the Torah says: “And if the woman was not defiled, but was pure, then she shall be acquitted and she shall conceive” (Numbers 5:28).

Though Jastrow's dictionary [points to the](https://www.sefaria.org/Jastrow%2C_%D7%A4%D6%B0%D6%BC%D7%9C%D6%B7%D7%A1%D6%B0%D7%98%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%A8.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) definition of forgery, what is the origin or root of the word פְּלַסְתֵּר?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Hebrew Wiktionary](https://he.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%A1%D7%AA%D7%A8) has confirmed my suspicion, the word פְּלַסְתֵּר is of Greek origin, and it comes from [πλαστός](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%80%CE%BB%CE%B1%CF%83%CF%84%CF%8C%CF%82), meaning

> - invented, artificial
> - false, spurious, fictitious, counterfeit

This is also, how [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.31b.10?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) translates it. The Greek word is derived from [πλάσσω](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%80%CE%BB%CE%AC%CF%83%CF%83%CF%89#Ancient_Greek), meaning *to form or mould,* and in a figurative sense *to fabricate or forge.*

Comment: from Klein "PBH forgery, fraud. [Gk. plaste, plastes (= molder, modeler), hence ‘forger’, from plassein (= to mold, form, model). cp. פּֽלַסְטִי, פּֽלַסְמָה.]"